# What does the Plumbing Code say about securing a bathtub faucet to the studs?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, building-regulations, code-compliance

My son is renting an apartment.  It looks as if the bathtub faucet (spout and valvehandle) are only secured by the grout of the tile and haven't been properly secured at all to the studs.  I know that most counties have their own amendments to the International building Code, but what is the bare minimum?  Should the faucet be secured by more than just tile grout??

Can someone point me to the code section that would define this?

Comment: First question I have is 'how can you tell'?

Comment: He fell on it and it broke the tile and can be jiggled around like a spring... When it happened, apparently the cold water line popped off causing water in the apartment downstairs...

Comment: So him falling on it with enough force to break the tile itself could have caused the bracing to separate...  Sounds like tenant responsibility to this landlord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at item 2, from section P2705 of the [2006 International Residential Code](http://publicecodes.citation.com/icod/irc/2006f2/icod_irc_2006f2_27_sec005.htm).

> **SECTION P2705 INSTALLATION**
>
> **P2705.1 General.**
>
> The installation of fixtures shall conform to the following:
>
> 1. Floor-outlet or floor-mounted fixtures shall be secured to the drainage connection and to the floor, where so designed, by screws,
>      bolts, washers, nuts and similar fasteners of copper, brass or other
>      corrosion-resistant material.
> 2. Wall-hung fixtures shall be rigidly supported so that strain is not transmitted to the plumbing system.
> 3. Where fixtures come in contact with walls and floors, the contact area shall be water tight.
> 4. Plumbing fixtures shall be usable.
> 5. The centerline of water closets or bidets shall not be less than 15 inches (381 mm) from adjacent walls or partitions or not less than
>      15 inches (381 mm) from the centerline of a bidet to the outermost rim
>      of an adjacent water closet. There shall be at least 21 inches (533
>      mm) clearance in front of the water closet, bidet or lavatory to any
>      wall, fixture or door.
> 6. The location of piping, fixtures or equipment shall not interfere with the operation of windows or doors.
> 7. In areas prone to flooding as established by Table R301.2(1), plumbing fixtures shall be located or installed in accordance with
>      Section R324.1.5.
> 8. Integral fixture-fitting mounting surfaces on manufactured plumbing fixtures or plumbing fixtures constructed on site, shall meet
>      the design requirements of ASME A112.19.2 or ASME A112.19.3.

Comment: In general would this still apply to an Apartment complex?  The notes on that link indicate 1- or 2-family dwellings.

Comment: @JayStevens That's a good question, I'm not a code expert so I'm not sure.  I would assume this is a standard practice, and I can't see why it would be different in a multi-family building.

Comment: @JayStevens If you intend to confront the land lord in an attempt to effect repairs I would consult a local authority or an attorney.

Comment: Unless the apartment building is new or the unit's plumbing was recently updated, referring to current code is likely pointless.  Old construction is generally grandfathered unless it's touched by new work.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo That is true, however, I believe this has been in existence for quite some time.  I was only able to verify this back to 2000, but I'm sure this has been standard for far longer than that.

Comment: Possibly - but then the fixture could have been installed properly to start and later came loose.

Comment: There's literally ZERO evidence when you look inside the wall that it was ever secured by anything other than the grout; these apartments were supposedly completely renovated 2 years ago... and are definitely newer than 2000.

Comment: @JayStevens you have the wall open?  are there screw holes (attachment points) on the valve?  Is there anything the valve could be attached to (cross brace)?